# How can I run condition in vue component before run html in the template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

My vue component like this :

```
<template>
    <div id="modal-transaction" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        ...
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">{{order.number}}</h4>
            </div>
        ...
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        ...
        data() {
            return {
                order: []
            }
        },
        watch: {
            orderDetail: {
                handler() {
                    this.order = this.orderDetail
                },
                immediate: true
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

If the code executed, there exist error like this :

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'number'
>   of undefined"

So I need a condition in the `watch`. If `this.orderDetail`has existed, then run html tag in the template. The error occurs because there is no condition like that. I am still confused to make the condition

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why orderDetails is not being used directly? I mean, why you have to set orderDetails to orders first?

Comment: @anasceym Because I use `watch`

Comment: Then why you use watch?

Comment: @anasceym for check orderDetail exist or no

Comment: Then why dont you use orderDetails in the html? You can check using v-if

Comment: @anasceym Yes it can. But there are several reasons why I use `watch`

Comment: Well for me it is bad design there, atleast I dont lnow the full context of what you are trying to achieve. To be very direct, the error above is because order is an array, but in the html you are accessing it with .number which expecting order is an object

Answer (score 0):

Technicaly the beforeUpdate hook can be used for that. Have a look at it:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeUpdate

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are accessing an array in your template as an object. So, if it's an array, use a v-for to loop over the order array and then access it. But I don't think you would want a for loop in the header. So expose a computed property that returns the appropriate element of your order array and use that in the template.

The second point, your error message. According to the [Vue Instance Life Cycle Hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks), the template is loaded after data is ready. But in your case, the watcher is firing after the template loads. So you are getting undefined error. There are 2 things you can do:

1: Have a loader displayed until your watcher fires and your order array has the appropriate data. Then you can use a method to get the element from the 'orderDetails' array.

```
<template>
<div id="modal-transaction" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    ...           
        <div v-if="orderNumber" class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">{{orderNumber}}</h4>
        </div>
        <!-- have some loader -->
        <div v-else class="loader" ></div>
    ...
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    ...
    data() {
        return {
            order: [],
            orderNumber: null
        }
    },
    watch: {
        orderDetail: {
            handler() {
                this.order = this.orderDetail;                   
                this.orderNumber = this.getOrderNumber();
            },
            immediate: true
        }
    },
    methods: {
      getOrderNumber() {
        //process this.orderDetail to get the appropriate orderNumber
      }
    }
</script>
```

2: If possible, have the 'orderDetails' array ready before you trigger the modal.